SDAnimatedImageView as drop-in replacement NSImageView
I currently have an NSImageView using a .gif from my bundle setup in storyboard/nib, but my GIF isn't working on all systems and so I want to try swapping in SDAnimatedImageView.
However when changing the class of my image view to SDAnimatedImageView, I find that the image object it loads based on the file set in interface builder is a normal NSImage, not a SDAnimatedImage. So not a seamless drop-in upgrade :^(
I'm guessing I need to call sd_setImage with a file URL to my .gif. I'd like that to remain specified in interface builder however, and is seems my only option to do so is for my view/window controller to dig the URL out of the NSImage, replaces it with an SDAnimatedImage built from that same URL.
Do I have this right? If so I can't possibly be the first to want to do this, does anybody have tips on the last part? It looks like I have to dive into the bitmap representations where the source URL might still be found.

Oh, of course, an NSImage has a name() method, which is the image name directly from interface builder. It's not a path URL, missing file extension for example, but I don't mind my view controller making the assumption that it can be found with SDAnimatedImage(named: name + ".gif")
